# Pandas normalize list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

I am currently trying to edit data from Mongo DB. I was already able to read the data into a dataframe. However, I have the problem that in the dataframe a column contains a list of dicts. I already tried to edit the data with pd.json.normalize, but I get the error 'float' object has no attributes 'values'. How can I convert the column into a new dataframe?

The dataframe looks like that:

| status | message | vars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | ok | [{'key': 'A1', 'value': '1', 'vartype: '1'}, {'key': 'A2', 'value': '0', 'vartype: '1'}, {'key': 'A3', 'value': '1', 'vartype: '1] |

I get the following error message when I execute this line:

```
df3 = pd.json_normalize(df3['vars'])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-da47e4ddf140> in <module>
----> 1 df3 = pd.json_normalize(df3['vars'])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    268 
    269     if record_path is None:
--> 270         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
    271             # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
    272             # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    268 
    269     if record_path is None:
--> 270         if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
    271             # naive normalization, this is idempotent for flat records
    272             # and potentially will inflate the data considerably for

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df3 = pd.json_normalize(df3['vars'].dropna())
```

Comment: I keep getting: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @SyrixGG - How working `import json` and then `df3 = pd.json_normalize(df3['vars'].apply(json.loads))` ?